# Help. I ran "find / -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;" by accident!

Tags: linux, rm

I'm very very tired, worked all night long, and I did't sleep for hours... So I'm like a zombie now... half awake, and half asleep.

I was trying to clear a directory. Then I run the command cd to enter the directory, and then before thinking I run this dangerous command. on my Linux server:

```
 "find  / -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;"
```

I got a lot of:

```
rm: cannot remove `/sys/module/serio_raw/sections': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove `/sys/module/pcspkr': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove `/sys/module/pcspkr/sections': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove `/sys/module/dm_raid45': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove `/sys/module/dm_raid45/sections': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove `/sys/module/dm_message': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove `/sys/module/dm_message/sections': Is a directory
```

**Could this command have deleted something inside these directories**? I'm afraid that the next reboot the server won't startup...

thanks.

Comment: Yes, you're royally screwed unless you have backups. You _do_ have backups, don't you? If so, use them, if not consider this a valuable life lesson and (once you extricated yourself from this unholy mess) start doing them both regularly and frequently.

Comment: What is your FS? Would you study a File System Forensics? I already did this for FFS2 FS after a rm-rf (several TB of data).

Comment: fortunatelly, it looks like nothing was removed. I stopped the commando, before it leaving the /sys directory, that was the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/sys`, like `/proc` is a virtual directory. You cannot really delete anything in there - certainly nothing that a reboot won't restore.

The same can't be said about your on-disk filesystems though. `rm` without `-r` won't delete a directory, but along with `find` it can easily delete all files under it. The `-mtime +1` sort of restricts the extent of the damage, but does not prevent it.

You might want to use your package management system to at least verify the system files before rebooting. Also, check with `find /` in what order are the directories listed. Perhaps you got lucky and `/sys` was the first - you did interrupt the command right away, right?

Comment: It looks like nothing was deleted: When I run find / as you said, I got: root@server [/sys]# find /
/
/sys
/sys/module
/sys/module/ipt_owner
/sys/module/ipt_owner/sections

Comment: is there any log where is stored a list with everything that could have been deleted?

Comment: @Valter: no, there is no log. However, the order `find` presents the contents of a directory is the native order of the filesystem and does not change unless you add/remove something. Running `find /` would show you the order in which the directories were accessed.

Comment: That said, you should use your package management system to verify the system files and you should probably compare with your backups for missing files. If you have setup `locate` you might also use `locate /` and a bit of shell trickery to find missing files since the last time the `locate` DB was updated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes: rm fails deleting directories, but find "digs" inside them, if it can, and calls rm on files contained